# ANSWERED: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' but it's at the end of the object

Tags: javascript, json

I am parsing a JSON string to a JSON object and am getting the above error at line 1 column 120 (the last character in the object).

This is the string in question:

`{"{\"sender\":\"jeff\",\"recipient\":\"bill\",\"type\":\"friend-request\",\"viewed\":false,\"timestamp\":\"8/5/2019\"}"}`

being accessed here as user.notifications:

```
const displayNotifications = async function() {
    if (!user.notifications) {
      setNotifications(
        (
          <div key="0">
            <p>You have no notifications to check!</p>
          </div>
        ));
    } else {
      setNotifications(await JSON.parse(user.notifications).map((notification, i) => {
        if (notification.type === "friend-request") {
          return <FriendRequestNote key={i} notification={notification} />
        } else if (notification.type === "friend-accept") {
          return <FriendAcceptNote key={i} notification={notification} />
        }
        return true;
      }));
    }
  }
```

I have run it through JSONLinter, and it gives me the same error. Can't seem to figure out why exactly it wants me to put a colon at the end of the object.

Comment: You've defined a very long object key, but no value for it, so it throws an error. If you want just a plain value, you should use an array, or a property alone, not an object

Comment: is double stringify -> put `JSON.parse('{\"send........./2019\"}')`

Comment: This is it. I'm hunting through right now to see where I've managed to pick up two extra curly braces. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have gotten an extra {} around your object. I would sugest using `{\"sender\":\"jeff\",\"recipient\":\"bill\",\"type\":\"friend-request\",\"viewed\":false,\"timestamp\":\"8/5/2019\"}` 
instead.

Otherwise you are using an object with a string in it and json requires a key value structure for objects.

Answer (score 0):

This would be valid RFC 4627 ([JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159)).

```json
{
   "sender": "jeff",
   "recipient": "bill",
   "type": "friend-request",
   "viewed": false,
   "timestamp": "8/5/2019"
}
```

How do you extract or generate your JSON?

Comment: The app I'm making grabs the user info and the target user info and makes an object which is then stringified so that it can be stored in the database.

Comment: Please update your question with the code which is used in your app.